# File encryption is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried using the `File.Encrypt(string path)` and the `File.Decrypt(string path)` methods in `dotnet core 2.1.1`, but I keep getting an `IOException` with the message `File encryption is not supported on this platform.`.

I do not know what I am missing. I have searched the Internet with no success. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the message is quite clear, this api is not available on your plattform. You have to resort to some own or third party implementation.

Comment: What platform is it?

Comment: @Attersson It's on Windows 10.

Comment: @ShittuJosephOlugbenga: Home edition, by any chance? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=netstandard-2.0#System_IO_File_Encrypt_System_String_) explicitly state: "his method is not available on all versions of Windows. For example, it is not available on Home editions."

Comment: Judging from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx) this API heavily relies on availability of BitLocker, hence won't work on non-enterprise editions of Windows (and non-Windows platforms in general).

Comment: @Daisy, it's  Home Edition

Comment: In which case, unfortunately, you have your answer...

Comment: @Orhtej2 that is a serious setback. Thanks.

Comment: @thehennyy the message is not quite clear... He's using 2.1 and based on the documentation, it is supported... I am having the same issue with 2.0.. Please any Microsoft people in the house?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.decrypt?view=netcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

The major problem was the edition of my Windows OS. I am using the Home Edition of Windows 10, which does not support `File.Encrypt(string path)`. It is not a dotnet core problem. it's the platform (Windows OS) where the application is running. Hence the error message `File encryption is not supported on this platform` is very much correct.